# "Cannot unpack non-iterable float object error " in Scipy's ivp

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate a second-order ODE using Scipy's ivp. I have separated the 2nd order ODE into a system of two first-order ODE's using  Sympy. This is the code I am using

```
""" Sympy """
import sympy as smp
import sympy
import numpy as np

""" Scipy """

from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

""" Define symbols"""
t,m,q, c = smp.symbols('t m q c', Real =True)
x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, Ex, Ey, Ez, Bx, By, Bz, gamma = smp.symbols('x y z v_x v_y v_z  E_x E_y E_z B_x B_y B_z gamma ',cls=smp.Function, real=True)

""" Define functions"""

x    = x(t);                y   = y(t);               z    = z(t);                 # Position   
vx   = vx(t);              vy   = vy(t);              vz   = vz(t);                # Velocity  
Ex   = Ex(x, y, z, t);     Ey   = Ey(x, y, z, t);     Ez   = Ez(x, y, z, t);       # Components of E field 
Bx   = Bx(x, y, z, t);     By   = By(x, y, z, t);     Bz   = Bz(x, y, z, t);       # Components of B field
vx_d = smp.diff(vx,t);    vy_d = smp.diff(vy,t);    vz_d = smp.diff(vz,t);         # d^{2}x_{i}/dt^2 , i  = x, y, z 

""" Define Matrices"""
r      = smp.Matrix([x, y, z])
E      = smp.Matrix([Ex, Ey, Ez])
B      = smp.Matrix([Bx, By, Bz])
v      = smp.Matrix([vx, vy, vz])

""" Define gamma """
v_norm = v.norm()
gamma  = gamma(v_norm)
gamma  = 1/smp.sqrt(1 - (v.norm()/c)**2)

""" Define momentum """
p    = m*gamma*v

""" 2nd order ODE of motion """
de1 = smp.diff(p,t)-q*(E +v.cross(B)/c)

""" Solve for dv_{i}/dt, i = x, y, z """ 
sols   = smp.solve([de1[0],de1[1], de1[2]], (vx_d, vy_d, vz_d),real=True, Simplify =False, rational=False)

"""Create numpy functions that we can use with numerical methods"""
list_p = (c, m, q, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, Ex, Ey, Ez, Bx, By, Bz)

vx  = smp.diff(x,t);      vy  = smp.diff(y,t);      vz  = smp.diff(z,t);        # dx_{i}/dt ,    x_{i} = x, y, z

dvx_dt_f  = smp.lambdify(list_p,sols[vx_d], modules=np)
dx_dt_f   = smp.lambdify(vx,vx, modules=np)

dvy_dt_f  = smp.lambdify(list_p,sols[vy_d], modules=np)
dy_dt_f   = smp.lambdify(vy, vy, modules=np)

dvz_dt_f  = smp.lambdify(list_p,sols[vz_d], modules=np)
dz_dt_f   = smp.lambdify(vz, vz, modules=np)



def dSdt(S,t,c_n, mp_n, q_n):
    vx, x, vy, y, vz, z = S
    
    return[dvx_dt_f(c, m, q, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, Ex, Ey, Ez, Bx, By, Bz),
           dx_dt_f(vx),
           dvy_dt_f(c, m, q, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, Ex, Ey, Ez, Bx, By, Bz),
           dy_dt_f(vy),
           dvz_dt_f(c, m, q, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, Ex, Ey, Ez, Bx, By, Bz),
           dz_dt_f(vz)
          ]

"""Define constants"""
# constants (cgs units)
mp_n   = 1.673e-24                             # ion (proton) mass
mp2e_n = 1836.15267389                         # proton to electron mass ratio
qe_n   = 4.803e-10                             # elementary charge
c_n    = 2.998e10                              # speed of light
kB_n   = 1.3807e-16                            # Boltzmann constant
vth_n  = np.sqrt(kB_n*T_n/mp_n)                 # ion thermal speed




"""Solve ODE """
sol = solve_ivp(dSdt, (0,10), y0=[vth_n, 0, vth_n, 0,vth_n,0], method='RK45', t_eval=None,args=(c_n, mp_n, qe_n,))
```

However, I get the following error:

**Cannot unpack non-iterable float object**
The error occurs when I try to define the dSdt function

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: you post a whole screen of code, and don't even tell us where the error occurs? :(

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have added a comment to indicate the location of the error!

Comment: The error tells us that `S` the argument the `dSdt` gets is a single float number, not the array or list of 6 that the unpacking expects.  I need to take more time to trace that `S` back to your parameters, but I suspect it comes from `y0` initial condition(s) parameter.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer would help a lot! I have been struggling to fix this for two days and was not able to trace the error!

Comment: For `solve_ivp` the function signature is supposed to be `fun(t, y)` (see the docs).  That is, the first argument is the scalar time, and the second the `y` (which according to your `y0` is big enough).  You have them reversed in `dSdt`.

Comment: Your code has some incorrect capitalisations like `Real` and `Simplify`. Those won't work properly if you capitalise the first letter.